# ArcGIS Pro 3.1 AddIn doesn't work with: System.ServiceModel

Tags: add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk

My ArcGIS Pro 3.1 AddIn uses System.ServiceModel to open a communication via pipes to a service. I added "System.ServiceModel" to the Assablies (References) and Built it without errors.

But when I debug my AddIn and the button is clicked where the connection should be established:

```
var pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IWCFStarter>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                                                  new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/myconnect"));
```

An exception is thrown:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
  Source=ARCBAR
```

So why is this? It works fine with referencing my own projects.

Things I tried that didn't work:

- Rebuild everything.
- Set the 'Copy local' in the properties of the Assembly: 'System.ServiceModel' to yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all references to: System.ServiceModel from all projects in the workspace. Then I added the nuget-Packages:

```
System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipe and
System.ServiceModel.Primitives
```

Afterwards the code compiles and runs.